# Get Time interval between two NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have two dates like **startDate = 2016-02-24 10:25:11 +0000** and **endDate = 2016-02-24 10:26:11 +0000**.

I want to find time interval between these dates in seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have tried this but it is giving me wrong calculation. When i made difference of 10 minutes between dates. It is giving me result of 5.
I have tried this code - 

    NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [sDate timeIntervalSinceDate:eDate];
    double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
    NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this can help you.

```
NSString *startDate = @"2016-02-24 10:25:11 +0000";
NSString *endDate = @"2016-02-24 10:26:11 +0000";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *start = [formatter dateFromString:startDate];
NSDate *end = [formatter dateFromString:endDate];

NSTimeInterval interval = [end timeIntervalSinceDate:start];
NSLog(@"time interval:%f", interval);
```

Comment: Output: `time interval:60.000000`